# Wcf - Hiding Properties?

Tags: c#, wcf, datamember

I've got a class which looks a little like this....

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Area : ModelBase
{
    private String name;
    private Guid floorId;
    private Guid areaTypeId;
    private int assetCount;

    [DataMember] 
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember] 
    public Guid FloorId
    {
        get { return floorId; }
        set { floorId = value; }
    }

    public Guid AreaTypeId
    {
        get { return areaTypeId; }
        set { areaTypeId = value; }
    }
}
```

....and I have a Wcf Service Library which has the following interface defined...

```
 IEnumerable<Area> GetSomeStuff(IEnumerable<Area> uploadedAreas);
```

It's all working just fine, but in my client app (a compact framework application) the `AreaTypeId` property is exposed?

I thought that if I didn't add the `[DataMember]` attribute it wouldn't be seen by the client?  What am not understanding???

Thanks,

ETFairfax

Comment: how did you create the proxy on your client? Add WebReference or you used NetCFSvcUtil?

Comment: @pdiddy: What does it matter how the client is created? The OP wants (as far as I can see) to avoid sending the blasted property over the wire completely, not just make the client ignore it.

Comment: Just in case it does make a difference, I used "Add Web Reference"

Comment: @Fyodor, I originally thought that going through the Add Web Reference way might not have consider the DataMember attribute, since the Add Web Reference is more for ASMX web service. But after doing a quick test, it does take into account the attribute. ETFairfax you can disregard my comment, or if you have generated the proxy through adding web reference, you can try to use the NetCFSvcUtil and see if you have the same behavior.

Comment: @pdiddy, I ran netcfsvcutil (which I hadn't heard of before this post and had an error message pop-up!!  Apparently there isn't a fix....

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/06/26/netcfsvcutil-exe-and-windows-7.aspx

Comment: you can check this guidance here on using WCF on mobile device: http://wcfguidanceformobile.codeplex.com/  I had the same issue with Windows7 and netcfsvcutil, i remembered i had to download a patched version of netcfsvcutil to generate the proxies without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sharing type assembly between client and server It will  be visible unless you turn off reusing types from referenced assemblies (click "Configure Service Reference" on proxy).

If you are not sharing assembly it will not be visible because code for class is generated based on exposed contract (you can see it by turning on Show All Files in VS and then go to generated file Reference.cs under service proxy).

DataMember is attribute for [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) so if you are sharing assembly the property will be not serialized on server and not initialized on client but it will be visible. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx)

Comment: It's called "sharing" - "to shear" is what you do to sheep or such - remove their hair once in a while

Comment: @baalazamon

Thanks for the reply.

I'm right clicking the Web Reference in the Smart Device project, and it doesn't show "Configure Service Reference".  Is this because it is a Smart Device project.  I'm running VS2008 by the way. 



Also, I'm (not as far as I know) sharing the assembly.  I have a dll with the Model in (as shown above) a Wcf Service Library which references the Model.dll, and then the Smart Device application which has a Web Reference to the Wcf Service Library.

Comment: Configure Service Reference is only available through the Add Service Reference, which is not avail for Smart Device

Comment: I didn't see the compact client at first but I can assure you the data will not be sent over the wire if they are not marked with DataMember attribute you can check that easily by throwing exception in setter if serializer is setting property it will fail.

Comment: I've ended up backing out of using a Wcf Service Application for my projectm I thought I'd mark this as the answer just in case others find the same problem.....it might help?!?!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide any property from client then just add **[IgnoreDataMember]** attribute to that property.